# Union multiple tables with non-matching columns

Tags: sql, hive

I wanted to combine multiple tables in Hive using the UNION command. The problem is that they have non-matching columns. I know I can use something like the following:

```
SELECT col_a, NULL AS col_b, NULL AS col_c
FROM table_a
UNION
SELECT NULL AS col_a, col_b, NULL AS col_c
FROM table_b
UNION
SELECT NULL AS col_a, NULL AS col_b, col_c
FROM table_c
...
```

but this doesn't scale very well when there are a large number of tables I need to query, especially when I want all the columns from each table. Is there a more concise query I can use?

Comment: _" Is there a more concise query I can use?"_ - Is there a reason you can't use multiple resultsets?

Comment: @Dai I can make individual calls, but it would have been more convenient to retrieve all the data at once for my scenario.